# Multiple Connection and Multiple Flow

Tags: c, sockets, tcp

What is difference between multiple TCP connection and Multiple TCP Flow. I am little with confused, I want to generate High speed traffic generator. I need some clarification about this.Both are same or Different? In term of Socket, Multiple connection can be establish using single socket, but it doesn’t start multiple flow .

Answer (score 0):

Connection is based on the hosts and flows are based on the processes. TCP server to TCP client flow is basically describes properties of the connection , like data rate,direction etc.

Sakthivel S

Comment: Now if I want to Generate Multiple flow , its mean establishing Multiple connection simply ??

Comment: May be yeah. a tcp connection will have 2 flows. One is for forward direction and another one is for reverse direction.

Comment: Then what is difference in creating flow using same socket or using differrent socket. Performance wise which one will be better .